# Why do I get 0 as the second number even though I entered 66?

Tags: c++, scanf

[image]
[image]

Why do I get 0 as the second number even though I entered 66 ?

Comment: please add your code as text: ``` your_code  ```

Comment: Your switch statement can't work.

Comment: If you copy and paste the text - which is _at least_ as easy as attaching a screenshot - then other people can copy and paste it locally to try reproducing the problem, and test solutions. No-one is going to OCR a screenshot, so it's much harder, in general, for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

scanf("%s",&a) is incorrect as you read a single char.
Try one of those:

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

or

```
scanf("%c",&a);
```

Comment: To clarify: the `%d` is for reading a number, and the `%c` for a single character. For the operation to perform, `%d` also won’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `printf` and `scanf` are included from [`<cstdio>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdio) in C++. The `<stdio.h>` header is used in C.

Secondly, you can see that [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) returns a value - you should always check this. If an error occurs (or a conversion fails), then trying to debug the result of ignoring it is much more difficult than just checking in the first place.

Thirdly, you can see the conversion specifier `%s`

> Always stores a null character in addition to the characters matched (so the argument array must have room for at least width+1 characters)

because it is reading a *string* of characters. You've passed the address of a single character, which means you're almost certainly going to write outside it and see undefined behaviour. Using `%s` without a width specifier is always dangerous (ie, don't do it).

You can use `%c` to read a single character, or you can read a string (into an actual character array) and check the length and contents later, or you can use the C++ streams and make your life much easier.